# Find out relative urls in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to know if the url is relative or no using javascript. Basically  i will be passed the url, if the url is relative append the current url i.e  minus the file name. Can some one help me with this

eg:-

> **CURRENT URL** = http://example.com/big/index.html
>
> **PASSED URL 1** = newindex.html
>   **OUTPUT** = http://example.com/big/newindex.html
>
> **PASSED URL 2** = http://mysite.com/big/newindex.html
>   **OUTPUT** = http://mysite.com/big/newindex.html

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems have you encountered? Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: You can check for the presence of http:// in the beginning of the string. Are there any exceptional cases apart from the above examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var loc = location.href;
    var baseurl = loc.substring(0,loc.lastIndexOf('/'));

    function getoutputurl(inputurl)
    {
        var returnurl = '';
        if (inputurl)
        {
            if(inputurl.toLowerCase().indexOf('http://')==0)
            {
                returnurl = inputurl;
            }
            else
            {
                returnurl =  baseurl+'/' ;
                if(inputurl.indexOf('/')==0)
                {
                    returnurl = returnurl + inputurl.substring(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    returnurl = returnurl + inputurl;
                }
            }
        }
        return returnurl;
    }

    alert(getoutputurl('http://google.com'));
    alert(getoutputurl('google.com'));
</script>
```

Try out this code it works

Answer (score 2):

So the simplest would be something like

```
var loc = location.href;
var dir = loc.substring(0,loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
function getHref(urlString) {
  if (urlString) return (urlString.toLowerCase().indexOf('http:')==0)?urlString:dir+'/'+((urlString.indexOf('/')==0)?urlString.substring(1):urlString);
}
```

I am using the [location object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp), [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp), indexOf[link text](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp), [lastIndexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp) and the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788917/javascript-ternary-operator) - nested

Comment: one bug in the cod please fix it "? urlString.substring(1) " to "? urlString.substring(1) : urlString);"

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expresion to check if passed url have non relative component. If not create new output url based on part of current url ( cuted via regular exp also for example) and relative part.