# Checking image name using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm changing the img src on click using javascript.

I'm trying to determine whether to switch on or off.

I'm testing the following:

```
var img_el = document.getElementById("on_off_img");
if ( img_el.src == 'img/on.png' ) {

  img_el.src = 'img/off.png'
} else {

  img_el.src = 'img/on.png'
}
```

My problem is that i never get a match - it looks like img_el.src returns the full URL... Is there a function to just test the actual filename instead of the full string to the file?

Or is there a better way to manage the click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use indexOf() instead of comparing the src

e.g

```
var img_el = document.getElementById("on_off_img");
if ( img_el.src.indexOf('on.png') > -1) {
  img_el.src = 'img/off.png'
} else {

  img_el.src = 'img/on.png'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yuo can always use `indexOf`:

```
if(img_el.src.indexOf('img/on.png') > -1){
  img_el.src = 'img/off.png'
}else{
  img_el.src = 'img/on.png'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To shorten this even more, you can use a [ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788917/javascript-ternary-operator) operator:

```
var img_el = document.getElementById("on_off_img"),
    isOn   = img_el.src.indexOf('on.png')>-1;
img_el.src = isOn ? 'img/off.png' : 'img/on.png';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **match** statement aswell.

```
var img_el = document.getElementById("on_off_img");
if ( img_el.src.match("on.png")) 
{
  img_el.src = 'img/off.png'
} else 
{
  img_el.src = 'img/on.png'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try using JQuery:**

```
$("#on_off_img").click(function(){
    if($(this)[0].nameProp == "on.png")
        $(this).attr("src","img/off.png");
    else
        $(this).attr("src","img/on.png");         
});
```