# How can I check if a cookie has been set using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I am using the following code:

```
$('#theme').attr('href', $.cookie("jquery-ui-theme"));
```

This works if the cookie has already been set. But how can I make a default href if the cookie has not yet been se

Answer (score 5):

Strange to see suggestions here for a ternary operator in which the first value is the same as the condition. Shorten it to:

```
$('#theme').attr('href', $.cookie('jquery-ui-theme') || "default");
```

You can always reduce the ternary expression `A ? A : B` to the simpler `A || B`

Comment: Also note that this is not particularly related to the jQuery cookie plugin but a general solution for default values

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript) which is essentially an if statement that fits on one line.  They're structured as:

> expression ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;

I tend to use them for situations like this where you want a default value if something isn't set.

```
var href = $.cookie("jquery-ui-theme") ? $.cookie("jquery-ui-theme") : 'http://www.example.com';
$('#theme').attr('href', href);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
var href = $.cookie("jquery-ui-theme");
if (!href) {
    href = 'http://www.example.com';
}
$('#theme').attr('href', href);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your cookie plugin, but just use a ternary operator (and modify this code for your plugin if needed):

```
$('#theme').attr('href', ($.cookie('jquery-ui-theme')!='') ? $.cookie('jquery-ui-theme') : 'your-default-value'))
```

See also:  [Operator precedence with Javascript Ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788917/javascript-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Check if it exists:

```
if ($.cookie('jquery-ui-theme') != null) {
  $('#theme').attr('href', $.cookie("jquery-ui-theme"));
} else {
  $('#theme').attr('href', 'default');
}
```