# Shortest way to write this in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to implement this:

```
//foo is a boolean
if(foo){
    count++;
} else {
    count--;
}
```

How could I write this with a one liner?

Comment: Less code is not always better (unless your sole criterion for "better" is less code, which is not sensible). But in this case one of the offered ternary operations is likely best.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
count += foo ? 1 : -1
```

Answer (score 11):

`foo ? count++ : count--;`

This is called a ternary operator, see [Operator precedence with Javascript Ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788917/javascript-ternary-operator)

Simplest explaination is:
`if this ? then this : else this`

Comment: In ES5 it's called the *[conditional operator (?:)](http://es5.github.com/#x11.12)*, though it is generlly called a *ternary expression* or *ternary operation*

Comment: I like this one because it's both brief and clear and I think it's even easier to read than Nikhil's answer.  I personally value clarity over brevity.  If you ever spend significant time working on other people's code, you will value the clarity aspect too.

Answer (score 5):

Using [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and javascripts [dynamic typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_typing) this should be the shortest:

```
count += foo || -1;
```

Comment: You're assuming that `foo` evaluates to 1, there is no reason to assume that from the OP, what if `foo = 12` or `foo = {…}`?

Comment: Citation from the OP: `//foo is a boolean`

Comment: Ok, missed the comment. Still a risky approach though.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest is to keep the logic you have now and convert to a ternary:

`count += foo ? 1 : -1;`

Answer (score 1):

You can treat `foo` as a number, specifically `1` or `0`:

```
count += 2 * foo - 1;
```

Comment: Except this code is completely unreadable...

Comment: The OP did ask for the "shortest" way (in the title of the question), not a short answer that was readable.  Personally, I find hkf's answer to be the most readable which is probably how I'd do it as I value clarity over brevity (which is the case for anyone who's had to spend a lot of time working/fixing other people's code).

Answer (score 0):

```
 count = (foo) ? count+1 : count-1;
```

Comment: `count++` and `count--` would make more sense here and then you don't even need the assignment.

Comment: Agreed. But any improvement of performance would be there?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
foo ? count++ : count--;
```

Comment: You don't need to assign to `count`.  The `count++` and `count--` take care of that already.