# Confused by shorthand syntax: x > 0 ? 1 : -1;

Tags: javascript, syntax, conditional-operator

What does the following Javascript syntax mean? Please describe the whole syntax:

```
var x = 0;
x > 0 ? 1 : -1;  // confused about this line
alert(x);
```

Comment: That's the [ternary operator][1] (the link explains it)

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788917/javascript-ternary-operator

Comment: It does nothing...

Comment: @DhaivatPandya The official name is the conditional operator. A ternary operator is just one with three operands.

Comment: Not a duplicate; the other question is about this operator's interaction with the compound assignment syntax.

Answer (score 20):

That on its own means nothing. You will alert `x`'s value, which is 0, and that's it. The second statement is meaningless unless you assign it to something. If however you would have done this:

```
var x=0;
var y = x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
alert(y);
```

You would have gotten -1.

**[The Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**, is a shorthand for IF statements, it basically says:

> Assert if `x > 0`. If so, assign 1. If not, assign -1.

Or on a more general form:

```
CONDITION ? VALUE_IF_TRUE : VALUE_IF_FALSE;
```

Where:

- `CONDITION` - can be anything which evaluates to a boolean (even after type juggling).
- `VALUE_IF_TRUE` - value to be returned in case `CONDITION` was asserted to `TRUE`.
- `VALUE_IF_FALSE` - value to be returned in case `CONDITION` was asserted to `FALSE`.

Comment: To expand on this, the `y=` line tests `x>0`. If that's true, `y` gets assigned `1`, if it's false then `y` gets assigned `-1`.

Comment: thnx truth that's was very helpful

Comment: @osami: If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it. It can be done by clicking the large green tick under this answer's vote count.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It's time I hit the bed.

Comment: I would probably not say this, but since he seems to be new to js and the tendency of copy-pasting at this point is big, so, I point out that it should be `var y` to avoid creating a global

Answer (score 2):

That is the **conditional operator**. It is a ternary operator because it has three operands. It is often referred to as the ternary operator but that terminology is rather loose since any operator with three operands is a ternary operator. It just so happens that is is the only commonly used ternary operator.

What does it mean? The expression

```
a?b:c
```

evaluates to `b` if `a` evaluates as true, otherwise the expression evaluates to `c`.

Answer (score 1):

this is a ternary operator (the ?)

Think of it like an IF statement.

the statement before the '?' is the condition of your if statement. Immediately what follows before the ':' is what will execute/be-assigned if the statement is true. After the ':' is what will execute/be-assigned if the statement is false.

Your code however will just alert 0 because you aren't assigning anything from your ternary operator.

basically your code might as well say.
`x = 0;
alert(x);
// this would alert 0`

you need to revise this to:
`x = 0;
var y = x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
alert(y);`

Answer (score 0):

It will be -1. This is known as the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

Basically it expands to this (assuming you meant to put `x=` at the beginning of the second line).

```
if(x>0){
  x = 1
} else {
  x = -1
}
```

Comment: The code in the question does not expand to that. There is no assignment in that statement.