# hard to read javascript code - single line logic to "demystify"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone demystify this line for me? 
It's javascript and it works fine, I just don't understand the exact logic behind the code. Maybe it would help to split the code into several lines or write it in c# or delphi for "comparison".
(I got it from here: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions)

many thanks!

```
$('#inlay-container').animate(
{
    left: parseInt($('#container').css('left'),10) == 0 ? +$('#container').outerWidth() : 0
}...
```

Comment: Your code is too long, "Extramystified": `left: $('#container').css('left')?0:$('#container').outerWidth()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#inlay-container').animate(
{
    left: parseInt($('#container').css('left'),10) == 0 ? + $('#container').outerWidth() : 0
}
```

`$('#container').css('left')` get the `left` position of `#container` set by `CSS`.

`parseInt($('#container').css('left'),10)` convert to integer that `left`.

Now you should know about ternary operator  `--- ? --- : ---`:

General if-else:

```
if(something) {
  alert('done');
} else {
  alert('not done');
}
```

In ternary it written as:

```
something ? alert('done') : alert('not done');
```

So `?` act as `if` and `:` act as `else`.

`$('#container').outerWidth()` get the width of `#container` including `padding` and `border`.

So therefore,

```
 parseInt($('#container').css('left'),10) == 0  ?  // if left of #container is 0

                   + $('#container').outerWidth() // then left increase to outerwidth

                    : 0                             // else left will set to 0
```

So above condition can also be written as

```
if($('#container').css('left'),10) == 0) {
   left = $('#container').outerWidth();
} else {
   left = 0;
}
```

#### At last, whole statement can be written as

```
var left = null;
if($('#container').css('left'),10) == 0) {
   left = $('#container').outerWidth();
} else {
   left = 0;
}

$('#inlay-container').animate({
    left: left
});
```

**Related refs:**

- **[Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**
- **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**
- **[.outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)**

Comment: ah I see!
I didn't know about the ternary operator. Thanks for everyone's advice!
So _"+$('#container').outerWidth()"_ basically means _"$('#container').outerWidth() = $('#container').outerWidth() + 1"_

Comment: @Yoschi - No it does not. What `+$('#container').outerWidth()` means is `turn the value return by $('#container').outerWidth() into number`. What you are saying (`outerWidth()+1`) is `++$('#container').outerWidth()`, which is a different thing.

Comment: why does it need to be translated into a number? I thought the `return` value here was already a number.

Comment: @Yoschi no it always return string

Comment: @Yoschi I've updated my answer with some links, please see them

Answer (score 2):

This is basically just a ternary expression. The form is `(bool) ? (true val) : (false val)`. What it is doing is animating the `#inlay-container` by setting the left value to either `+$('#container').outerWidth()` or `0` depending on the return of the statement `parseInt($('#container').css('left'),10) == 0` where we are comparing the left value of the `#container` to 0

Answer (score 1):

In plain language:

```
if #container's css left property is 0

   animate #inlay-container to right equal to the outer width of #container
else

   animate #inlay-container to left 0 from it's current position
```

We can elaborate that code into

```
var moveLeft;
if(parseInt($('#container').css('left'),10) == 0)
  moveLeft = $('#container').outerWidth();
else
  moveLeft = 0;
$('#inlay-container').animate(
{
    left: moveLeft
}
```

What it's using is a shorthand if else assignment. It's called `ternary operator` like

```
val =  condition? this : that
```

Read more [Operator precedence with Javascript Ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788917/javascript-ternary-operator) and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: I understood that it's doing a comparison etc but I see no if and else's, I have not seen code written like this before.I have no clue how to look this up since I'm not sure what to look up exactly.
Google doesn't accept "?" or "+" since they are single characters.
What is confusing me are both of these signs in relation to what they do as well as how the commands are chained up like this.

Comment: Updated my answer. You have to search with `ternary operator` . Most of the languages have this shorthand `if-else`

Comment: thanks, I don't mind such short code but when you see it for the first time... it's an abyss ^^

Answer (score 1):

What it means is

> Use `container`'s width as `inlay-container`'s `left` if `container`'s `left` is `0`, or else `inlay-container`'s `left` will be `0`.

---

### *Problem: "Demystified".*

```
parseInt($('#container').css('left'),10) == 0 ?  //if its left is 0
    +$('#container').outerWidth() :              //then use container's width
    0                                            //else use 0
```

This is what we called *Ternary operation* (or Ternary expression).
Read more: [Ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) <sup><sub>**(A Wikipedia search always comes in handy!)**</sub></sup>

---

Syntax:

```
(condition) ? ture : false ;

//which is the same as:
if(condition){
    true
}else{
    false
}
```

However, the **main difference** between them is that ternary expression can be used **inline**.

```
var txt = a>1 ? a : 0;  //Yup!

var txt = 0;            //Too long.
if(a>1){
    txt = a;
}
```

---

*Unrelated:*
Actually your code is a bit long IMO. I can shorten it even more:

```
left: +$('#container').css('left')?0:+$('#container').outerWidth()
```