# What does this syntax mean: ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to JavaScript, and so am still coming into small things that I don't quite understand and don't seem to appear when I search for them.
Please could somebody point me out what the ? : syntax is doing below.

```
var chCode = ('charCode' in event) ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788917/operator-precedence-with-javascript-ternary-operator

Comment: good read http://www.codecademy.com/courses/conditionals-in-javascript/4#!/exercises/0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). It's a short `if...else` statement.

Basically, your code can be expanded to this.

```
var chCode;

if ('charCode' in event) {
    chCode = event.charCode;
} else {
    chCode = event.keyCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

its the ternary operator

> The ?: operator can be used as a shortcut for an if...else statement. It is typically used as part of a larger expression where an if...else statement would be awkward.

```
var chCode = ('charCode' in event) ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;
```

same as

```
var chCode;

if ('charCode' in event) {
    chCode = event.charCode;
} else {
    chCode = event.keyCode;
}

test ? expression1 : expression2
```

> expression1 =An expression returned if test is true
>   expression2 = when false

Comment: `It is typically used as part of a larger expression where an if...else statement would be awkward.` How would a larger expression make an if/else "awkward"? And more importantly, how would using a ternary operator make it any less awkward?

Comment: @sachleen - you can't use an `if/else` in the middle of an expression. For assigning a variable to one of two values an `if/else` isn't too awkward, but you can use the ternary operator in _any_ expression, e.g., `someFunc(someCondition ? 12 : 19)` or `var greeting = "Hello " + (sex==="M"?"Mr":"Ms") + surname` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Is a [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

your code instead using `?` should look like

```
var chCode = ('charCode' in event) ? event.charCode : event.keyCode;


if('charCode' in event){
 chCode = event.charCode;
} else {
 chCode = event.keyCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it's a ternary.

You could make it terser with...

```
var chCode = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
```

Comment: not equivalent. `charCode` could be present but falsy

Comment: @JanDvorak Just like the `in` could find `charCode` on `Object.prototype`. For 99.9% of cases, it's finer to use this shorter code. There is no keycode for `0` as it's a control character that can't be typed.

Comment: You should not assume the browser does not set `charCode` to `null` if the key is not a character.

Comment: @JanDvorak: jQuery seems to do just that without causing problems: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L465

Comment: Given the OP _seems_ to be asking more about what the ternary operator does than how to use key and character codes I think Jan's point is correct that `||` is not equivalent. But yes, for key and character codes `||` is a reasonable shortcut.

Comment: @Blender jQuery (from the code you linked) checks if the `original.charCode` is weakly equal to null. `undefined == null`. This suggests the _code by OP_ is incorrect because it assumes the charCode cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

Translation:

```
var chCode;
if ('charCode' in event) chCode = event.charCode
else chCode = event.keyCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

**event.keyCode:** Returns the Unicode value of a non-character key in a keypress event or any key in any other type of keyboard event.

**event.charCode:** Returns the Unicode value of a character key pressed during a keypress event.

--

[LInk for event.KeyCode](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html)