# if condition in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying conditionally set the html content of an element, using the html method on the jquery object.
I am not sure which is the right way to do it. Wether to use an `if` statement inside the html method call, or something else

For example I am trying to set different sizes on an image using jquery.

```
if(settings.imagesize =='1') {
// do something 
 }
```

So I tried to put it in the html method as a parameter

```
.html(if(settings.imagesize=='1') { '<img src="image1.png"/>' })
```

To give you context for the above code, here is what the complete structure looks like:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
    var clone = drop.clone()
        .appendTo('body')
        .css(direction, Math.random() * jQuery(window).width() - 20)
        .css('top', snowTop)
        .html(
    if (i == '21') {})
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, can someone please help me with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do an if statement inside a method call, not like that atleast.

You can do a ternary if, if you really must.

```
.html(settings.imagesize=='1' ? '<img src="image1.png"/>' : '');
```

---

But **the most appropriate way** is handling all the logic before the call...

```
var content;
if(settings.imagesize=='1') 
{ 
    content = '<img src="image1.png"/>';
}
something.html(content);
```

---

If you **REALLY** need an if inside the html call, you can do it as an immediate function.

```
.html((function(){
    if(settings.imagesize=='1'){
        return '<img src="image1.png"/>';
    }
    else{
        return '';
    }
})());
```

***But then you are making your code hard to read...***

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this

```
var content = ''
if(settings.imagesize =='1') {
    content = '<img src="image1.png"/>'
}

.html(content)
```

EDIT

You can use a ternary operator like this for clear code.

```
var content = (settings.imagesize =='1') ? '<img src="image1.png"/>' : ''

.html(content)
```

This is much more readable instead of inline calling of if condition in `.html`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
.html((settings.imagesize == '1') ? '<img src="image1.png"/>' : 'other html');
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a silly question :)

This is how you can do this. Though I would not recommend doing such things. *You can do such manipulation outside.*

```
.html( settings.imagesize=='1'? '<img src="image1.png"/>' : '' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the ternary version of `if`

```
.html(i=='21' ? true : false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only one option.Try with `ternary operator`

```
.html((settings.imagesize=='1') ? '<img src="image1.png"/>' : '' )
```

But better you use `if` condition for this better than the `ternary`.

Comment: Is it possible to use the if condition inside html method ?

Comment: @User no, it would cause a Syntax Error (I believe)

Answer (score 1):

For your longer example, the same logic as the other answers follows:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
    var content = '';

    if(i == 21)
        content = 'something';

    var clone = drop.clone()
        .appendTo('body')
        .css(direction, Math.random() * jQuery(window).width() - 20)
        .css('top', snowTop)
        .html(content);
}
```

It looks like you may have some confusion around ternary vs if - they're essentially the same with the ternary just being a single if/else statement in shorthand notation:

```
if(something)
    thenDoThis();
else
    doThat();
```

Is the same as

```
something ? thenDoThis() : doThat();
```

The difference here is that `if` is not allowed inside a method call, whereas ternary statements are fine:

```
console.log(if(something){ thenDoThis(); });
// SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

console.log(something ? thenDoThis() : doThat());
// works fine
```

Answer (score 1):

can u check this

```
.html(i=='21' ? true : false)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788917/operator-precedence-with-javascript-ternary-operator):

```
.html((settings.imagesize=='1') ?'<img src="image1.png"/>' : '' )
```

But I think the better way is to **call a function**

```
.html(func(settings.imagesize));
function func(size){
     if(size === 1)
        return '<img src="image1.png"/>';
     return '';
}
```

or to use a **self calling function**:

```
.html(
(function func(size){
     if(size === 1)
        return '<img src="image1.png"/>';
     return '';
})(settings.imagesize));
```