# confusion with hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the below code, and some more, to quickly build a prototype for a 3 screen web application. Not planning to use it for production. The project is almost finished, but there is one issue that is perplexing me. I get an error - `Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined`, even though there is a check first whether the object has the property reported as undefined. Realize the code is not an example of how such things should be handled, but why does it not work? To prevent context funkiness, I even clone the array - probably unnecessary. What causes the undefined error?

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/v1/departures/' + routeID + '/',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Token '+ owner_token]
        },
        contentType:'application/json',
        success: function(departures) {
            console.log('departures: ' + JSON.stringify(departures));
            if ( departures && ( 0 < departures.length)) {
                var template = '';
                for ( var j = 0; j < departures.length; j++) {
                    if (departures[j].route == routeID) {
                        var seats = (departures[j].seats).slice(0);
                        for ( var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
                            template  += '<div class="right-seat" data-id="' + seats[i].seat + '">' +
                                 '<div class="right-seat-place">SEAT ' + seats[i].seat + '</div>' +
                                 '<div class="right-seat-name">' +
                                 seats[i].hasOwnProperty('passenger') ? seats[i].passenger.first_name + ' ' + seats[i].passenger.last_name : '' +
                                 '</div>' +
                                 '<div class="right-seat-reserved"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i>&nbsp;' +
                                 seats[i].hasOwnProperty('passenger') ? 'Reserved' : 'Available'  +
                                 '</div>' +
                                 '</div>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                $('div.right-top-controls').after(template);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error!');
        }
    });
```

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: passenger might not have a property first_name. There is no check for this.

Comment: that's true, but what does it have to do with either my question or the error?

Comment: Basically it seems your sear does have a property named passenger, but that is undefined, such as seat = {passenger:undefined}; seat.hasOwnProperty('passenger')

Comment: use `seats[i].passenger ? seats[i].passenger.first_name + ' ' + seats[i].passenger.last_name : ''` which will be false for `undefined`

Comment: @BenG that's a very good point, but the result is still the same - `Type Error: Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined`

Comment: thats not possible.

Comment: seats[i].passenger will check for null not undefined, you will need to use if typeof seats[i].passenger !== "undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) just checks if an object has a property by that name. It doesn't check what that value is. That value could be `undefined`.

```js
// Doesn't have the property and accessing it returns undefined
var A = {};
console.log(A.hasOwnProperty('prop'));
console.log(A.prop);


// Has the property and the value is not undefined
var B = {
  prop: 1
};
console.log(B.hasOwnProperty('prop'));
console.log(B.prop);

// Has the property AND it's value is undefined
var C = {
  prop: undefined
};
console.log(C.hasOwnProperty('prop'));
console.log(C.prop);
```

This means that `seats[i]` may very well have a `passenger` property but it's value could still be `undefined`.

There's also the problem that you're using a [ternary operation during string concatenation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788917) Essentially, `+` has higher precedence than `?:` which results in the concatenation occurring before the conditional is evaluated. To fix this, wrap your ternaries in parentheses.

```
template  += '<div class="right-seat" data-id="' + seats[i].seat + '">' +
               '<div class="right-seat-place">SEAT ' + seats[i].seat + '</div>' +
               '<div class="right-seat-name">' +
                 (seats[i].hasOwnProperty('passenger') ? seats[i].passenger.first_name + ' ' + seats[i].passenger.last_name : '') +
               '</div>' +
               '<div class="right-seat-reserved"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i>&nbsp;' +
                 (seats[i].hasOwnProperty('passenger') ? 'Reserved' : 'Available')  +
               '</div>' +
             '</div>';
```

Comment: makes sense. in my situation, it is unfortunately not the case.

Comment: @MosheShmukler Perhaps you should try `console.log(seats[i].passenger)` because the only way you can get that error is if that value is `undefined`. And the only way it will pass the `hasOwnProperty` check is if the object has a property by that name but with a value of `undefined`.

Comment: @MosheShmukler *" it is unfortunately not the case."* So what is the case?

Comment: I did dump my array to the console. It looks like: [{"seat":"1"},{"seat":"2"},{"seat":"3"},{"seat":"4"}]

Comment: @MosheShmukler See my edit. I believe I found your problem.

Comment: @MikeC adding brackets around the ternary does the trick. thank you.