# Why does assignment with help from ternary operator doesn't work as expected in JS?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, assignment-operator

```
var a = 0;
var param = 'add';
while(a < 50){
    console.log(a); //prints out values from 0 to 49
    if(param === 'add'){
        a = a + 1;
    }else{
        a = a - 1;
    }
}
```

While being very simple and doing its job, I would like to make this code shorter

```
while(a < 50){
    console.log(a);
    a = a + (param === 'add')? 1 : -1;
}
```

But a never grows and stays 1. Could anyone explain such behavior?

Comment: `a = a + ((param === 'add') ? 1 : -1);`

Comment: All the operations before `?` are considered as the condition part of the ternary.

Comment: Shorter is not the same as better. Your original code is much easier to read. And works.

Comment: I agree with Andy, although I would change `a = a + 1` to `a++` and `a = a - 1` to `a--`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Operator precedence with Javascript Ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788917/operator-precedence-with-javascript-ternary-operator)

Comment: `a += param === 'add' ? 1 : -1;`

Comment: Also if param is not add, your loop will never stop - `prints out values from 0 to 49 OR from 0 to -infinity`

Answer (score 1):

The expression is evaluated as

```
a = (a + (param === 'add')) ? 1 : -1;
```

which boils down to

```
a = 1;
```

You may solve this by writing

```
a = a + ((param === 'add') ? 1 : -1);
```

or even shorter:

```
a += (param === 'add') ? 1 : -1;
```

Comment: Why not just `a += param === 'add' ? 1 : -1;` ..?

Comment: Sure, I have appended this to my answer.